# Active Record Query where value in array field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, activerecord

I have a table called " Stat " in my MongoDB database in Rails 3 .

In that table, there is an array field called "services" .

I want to find all Stats that have a services array that contains the value "lights" .

I want to do something like this :

```
@stats = Stat.all
@stats1 =  @stats.where("services contains lights")
Rails.logger.info "result:  #{@stats1.count}  "
```

I've tried various things and Googled it extensively, found some leads but nothing that seems to work. I have four records that should match this query but the above returns a zero set.

Is what I want to do possible in rails 3 / mongo ?

Comment: What [Object Mapper](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center#RubyLanguageCenter-ObjectMappers) are you using to access MongoDB?  If you are using the native Ruby driver it does not implement ActiveRecord; you would instead be doing a [find()](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method) on a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to this question:

```
@stats =  @stats.where(:services.in =>['lights'] )
```

and I also found by poking around that the inverse is:

```
@stats =  @stats.where(:services.nin =>['lights'] )
```

`nin` instead of `in`

Comment: I understand this is old, but maybe you could link to where you found your answer?

Comment: I actually think I got the answer to this by asking one of my co-workers at the time, and then fiddling with it to find the "nin" variation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
@stats = Stat.all

@stats1 =  @stats.where("'lights' = ANY (services)")
```