# Active record where query for value inside of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sqlite, activerecord

Question: Is it possible to build a class method scope that can query objects based on values inside an array in a table?  If yes, how can I do this?

In my example, I have a “wells” table that has an array field called “well_tags”.  I want to build a query that returns all objects that have a specified value (such as “ceramic”) in the wells_tags array. The basic query would be something like this:

```
@well = Well.all
@query = @well.where(“well_tags contains ceramic”)
```

And then the class method scope would look something like this, with the “well_tag_search” param passed in from the controller:

```
class Well < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.well_tag_filter(well_tag_search)
  if well_tag_search.present?
    where(“well_tags contains ceramic")
  else
    Well.all
  end
end
```

I found another post that asks a similar question (see link below), but I cannot get the answer to work for me...the result is always 'nil' when I know there should be at least 1 object.  I am a beginner using sqlite (for now) as my database and rails 4.0.

[Active Record Query where value in array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888725/active-record-query-where-value-in-array-field)

Thanks!

UPDATE: some progress

I figured out how to create an array of all the objects I want using the ‘select’ method.  But I still need to return the results as an Active Record object so I create a class method scope.

```
@well = Well.select
        { |well| if well.well_tags.present?
        then well.well_tags.include? ‘ceramic' end }

@well.class #=> array
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where `Show` is coming from.

Can you try doing `Well.all` instead of `Show.all`?